# How to remove all children (but 2) from a parent element and append it to a new child element?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation in JS where I need to create a wrapper, add it to the astrology section after h2 and then append all the .box divs to the wrapper (there's 5 of them). Here's the code that I tried. The thing is that I don't know how to select .box divs without selecting the wrapper div. Any idea?

```js
astrology = document.querySelector('#astrology');
astrology.append('<div class="wrapper"></div>');

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#astrology > div'); //but not wrapper
wrapper.append('boxes');
```

```html
<section id="astrology">

    <h2>Астрологичекие услуги</h2>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-people-arrows"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Ваш персональный гороскоп</h3>
            <p>Кто я? Я, как личность.</p>
            <p>Мой характер, темперамент, предпочтения, особенности. Самооценка. Vita.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Гороскоп денег</h3>
            <p>Мои деньги. Мой заработок.</p>
            <p>Мои активы и ресурсы. Мои средства к существованию. Источники доходов. 
                Недвижимость. Имущество. Владения.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just don't append `#wrapper` to the DOM before selecting the "boxes", or use a more specific selector that only selects `<div>`s that have the class `box`, ... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: `wrapper.append('boxes');` won't do what you might expect it to do.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for telling me that the things I have tried, don't work. Didn't know that. 

Comment: `.append('boxes')` is not related to your actual question (_"I don't know how to select .box divs without selecting the wrapper div"_), so this was a hint for you. If you don't want tips on your code. Then sorry, but not sorry...

Comment: It was maybe a hint/tip in your mind but it is confusing, that's what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- createElement as a wrapper
- select box divs using the existing class `.box`

```js
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(boxElement => {
  wrapper.appendChild(boxElement);
});
document.getElementById('astrology').appendChild(wrapper);
```

```html
<section id="astrology">

    <h2>Астрологичекие услуги</h2>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-people-arrows"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Ваш персональный гороскоп</h3>
            <p>Кто я? Я, как личность.</p>
            <p>Мой характер, темперамент, предпочтения, особенности. Самооценка. Vita.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Гороскоп денег</h3>
            <p>Мои деньги. Мой заработок.</p>
            <p>Мои активы и ресурсы. Мои средства к существованию. Источники доходов. 
                Недвижимость. Имущество. Владения.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why `.createElement()`? It will also work with `.append()` like OP already does.

Comment: I understand now. Been going in circles, skipped forEach somewhere... Thank you very much, Zac.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
var selector = document.querySelector("#astrology");
selector.insertBefore(wrapper, selector.firstElementChild.nextSibling);
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(boxElement => {
  wrapper.appendChild(boxElement);
});
```

```html
<section id="astrology">

    <h2>Астрологичекие услуги</h2>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-people-arrows"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Ваш персональный гороскоп</h3>
            <p>Кто я? Я, как личность.</p>
            <p>Мой характер, темперамент, предпочтения, особенности. Самооценка. Vita.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>Гороскоп денег</h3>
            <p>Мои деньги. Мой заработок.</p>
            <p>Мои активы и ресурсы. Мои средства к существованию. Источники доходов. 
                Недвижимость. Имущество. Владения.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```